# SQL Database 2 Table Left Join and concatenate by ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

2 Table Joined by ID pointer on the 2nd Table.
A really old database that splits content into 8000 char, now I need to combine them again.

`[id]      ,[headline]      ,[body]      ,[body2]      ,[picname]
[picpath]      ,[postrelease]      ,[postdate]`

`[id]      ,[pr1id]      ,[body2]`

Pr1id points to the main data table. The Main data table's [body2] is a bool "yes" or Null.

I want both body to be combined into one in final output.

```
Select * FROM dbo.pressrelease_tbl m
LEFT JOIN dbo.pressrelease2_tbl m1
ON m1.pr1id = m.id
```

I am stuck on the concatenate part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`CONCAT()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231515.aspx) and make sure at least one of the strings is `nvarchar(max)`:

```
SELECT m.*, CONCAT(CAST(m.body AS nvarchar(max)), m1.body2) concatBody
FROM dbo.pressrelease_tbl m
LEFT JOIN dbo.pressrelease2_tbl m1
ON m1.pr1id = m.id
```

Comment: is there a string size limit? they all seems to be cut off halfway in the concatenate process ( really badly formatted ms word html.. )

Comment: Ohh I didn't realize that was your problem... Modifying answer.

Comment: can you add the ) closing Cast( so I can mark the correct answer? Thanks!

Comment: @vico - whooooppps :-)